# The order of a modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If $p$is prime and $\operatorname{ord}_p(a)=4$, then $1+a+a^2+a^3≡ 0\bmod p$, where $\operatorname{ord}_p(a)$ is the order of $a$ modulo $p$.

I think it is true statement

$\operatorname{ord}_p(a)=4$, then $a^4≡1\bmod p$ so $a^4-1≡0\bmod p$

since $a^4-1=1+a+a^2+a^3$, then $a^4-1=1+a+a^2+a^3\equiv0\bmod p$

is that correct please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^4-1 \neq 1+a+a^2+a^3$, but it is true that $a^4-1=(a-1)(a^3+a^2+a+1)=0 \mod p $, and since there are no zero divisiors, either $a=1$, in which case its order cannot be $4$,  or, as you conclude: $(a^3+a^2+a+1)=0$

Answer (score 2):

You can also find this directly since $4$ is conveniently small.

Since $p$ is prime, there are two roots of $1$: $\{1,-1\}$. Since $(a^2)^2\equiv 1$ but $a^2\not\equiv 1 \bmod p$ we must have $a^2\equiv \color{red}{-1} \bmod p$. Then $a^3\equiv a^2\cdot a \equiv \color{blue}{-a} \bmod p$.

Thus $1+a+a^2+a^3\equiv 1+a+ \color{red}{-1}+ \color{blue}{-a} \equiv 0\bmod p$.